# Can't create component 'Abp.Localization.ApplicationLanguageManager' as it has dependencies to be satisfied

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am getting the following error in ASP.net BoilerPlate

'Abp.Localization.ApplicationLanguageManager' is waiting for the following dependencies:

- Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[Abp.Localization.ApplicationLanguage, Abp.Zero, Version=0.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

The issue is attached as an image and I am using version 0.8.1.0

I have tried multiple ways to remove the references but still, we are getting the error

[Error in ABP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPogM.png)